# how to insert new line if a line has more than 60 characters

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text

I need to turn a text file that has a single line per file name and output separated by a single space into specific blocks that have lines that are equal to 60 characters in length.

Like this:

```
>Directory1/file3 CTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCCCCSCBCCCCCCCCSCTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCCCCSCBCCCCCCCCSCTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCCCCSCBCCCCCCCCS
>Directory1/file4 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
...
...
```

turn into

```
>Directory1/file3
CTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCCCCSCBCC
CCCCCCSCTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCC
CCSCBCCCCCCCCSCTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTT
TCCCCCCCCSCBCCCCCCCCS
>Directory1/file4
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
...
...
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk '{print $1; for (i=1;i<=length($2);i=i+60) print substr($2,i,60)}' file
>Directory1/file3
CTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCCCCSCBCC
CCCCCCSCTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCC
CCSCBCCCCCCCCSCTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTT
TCCCCCCCCSCBCCCCCCCCS
>Directory1/file4
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

How it works:

1. `print $1`

   This prints the first field on the line.
2. `for (i=1;i<=length($2);i=i+60) print substr($2,i,60)`

   For the second field on the line, we print 60 characters at a time until we reach the end of the field.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GNU coreutils [`fold`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fold):

```
fold -w60 file
```

Comment: you'd have first to put a new line iinstead of the first space, and then only pipe to your fold. `tr ' ' '\n' <file | fold -w60`  (assuming directory/filename is lower than 60 chars in length...)

Comment: Right! Read the question a bit too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

this looks okay too

```
sed -E "s/^(>[^\s]+) /\1\n/; s/([[:alnum:]]{60})/\1\n/g" /path/file
```

**result**

```
$ sed -E "s/^>([^\s]+) /\1\n/; s/([[:alnum:]]{60})/\1\n/g" /path/file
>Directory1/file3
CTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCCCCSCBCC
CCCCCCSCTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTTTCCCCCC
CCSCBCCCCCCCCSCTTSCCCTTTTTSEEEEECGGGSCEEEEECCCSSBCCCSCCCCCTT
TCCCCCCCCSCBCCCCCCCCS
>Directory1/file4
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
...
...
```

Comment: Regexes are neat but also not at all optimum here... Or maybe replace the `[[:alnum:]]` (very slow if locale is unicode) with a simple `.` to make it less CPU intensive?

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
fold -s -w 60
```

It produces the same output as in the question.

Assuming there are no spaces in the second part, this is the simplest way to do this.